# nested ng-repeat that one depend on the other

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatables, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an issue with angular, I want to use two nested ng-repeat in a data table where the first get the data, and the second get the name of field to be retrieved from the data (retrieved in the first ng-repeat) 
here is what I tried to do with code :

```js
<table md-table flex-order-gt-sm >
  <thead md-head>
    <tr md-row >
   //1st : get the name of fields, not a problem
        <th md-column ng-repeat="field in fields">{{item.name}}</th>
            </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody md-body>
       <tr md-row ng-repeat="item in items">
            <td md-cell ng-repeat="field in fields" >
   //here is the problem I want to get the item that it's field name is field
                     {{item.{{field}} }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

for example if fields contain :{'a','b','c'}
and items contains {'a':'1','b':'2','c':'3'};
I want for example for the 1st iteration of  {{item.{{field}} }} to return 1

Comment: you need to use bracket notation rather than dot notation here; i.e. `{{item[field]}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `toString()` to retrieve the scope data in an scope object.

```
<tr md-row ng-repeat="item in items">
    <td md-cell ng-repeat="field in fields" >
        {{item[field.toString()]}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

[Here is the plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/NDcmPG7RFvpNTtv8p4Y2?p=preview)

Comment: that seems to want I'm looking for, when I tried `{{item**.**[field.name.toString()] }}`  it doesn't work, I get an error

Comment: why did you take `field.name` again. you doesn't have in the question.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you could also use a filter:

```
<td md-cell ng-repeat="field in fields | filter: { name: 'field' }">                
</td>
```

Comment: it seems also correct, but the I think that I need the inverse, `item in items | filter :{name: field}` but the problem is item is the 1st and field is the 2nd so I can use this with item (because field doesn't exist yet

Answer (score 0):

You need to get fields collection according to item of items collection after

getFieldsByItem(item)

Then you can get field from fields collection

{{field}}